# How update a QQuickItem created only at C++ level

Tags: c++, qt, scenegraph, qtopengl, qquickitem

I have a `QQuickItem` derived class like below

```
class MyQQuickItem : public QQuickItem 
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyQQuickItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
  ~ MyQQuickItem();

  QSGNode *updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, UpdatePaintNodeData *);
};
```

I have my own `TextureNode` class as well.

I have `MyQQuickItem` registered on QML side & embedded in `main.qml` like below.

```
MyQQuickItem {
    id: my_quick_item
    objectName: "MyQQuickItemObject"
    visible: false
    width: 500
    height: 500
}
```

On the trigger of a certain signal, that I have connected to a slot in `MyQQuickItem`, I call `this->update()`. This of course triggers `updatePaintNode` & I am able to repaint my `MyQQuickItem` with new content I want.

**Is it possible** to trigger `updatePaintNode` on a `QQuickItem` without declaring it at all in a qml file?

I **want to dynamically create my `MyQQuickItem` at C++ level** & not have it defined or declared at all in `main.qml` How can I do this?

*Core question*: **How can I create a QQuickItem purely at C++ level which is updatable with new content by calling update on it so that updatePaintNode is fired?**

**Update:**
I am able to create a `QQuickItem` in the following way.

```
QQuickView * view = new QQuickView;
view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/MyQQuickItem.qml")));
QQuickItem * myquickitem_object = view->rootObject();
```

But the problem is that I cant get `updatePaintNode` to fire when I call `this->update`. **What should I do get the my `QQuickItem` to update itself?**

Comment: I think you don't need QQuickItem without displaying it in UI via QML. And if you want an access from C++ to the quick item used by QML is a different question.

Comment: You've been posting a series of questions that hint at you doing something wrong.

Comment: @dtech hahaha. whats wrong with this question?

Comment: is it not possible to to update a `QQuickItem` without putting it on QML?

Comment: Well, what good is a QML item without a QML engine and without a QML scenegraph renderer? Maybe you should clarify what you want to do rather than wasting time on things impossible.

Comment: I explained the background in above comment. it all boils down to **1.** whether I can create `MyQQuickItem` on the fly in C++ only? **2.** Or have `MyQQuickItem.qml` in my library & somehow make it capable of updating itself. note that I don't need to display `MyQQuickItem` on app's UI & I do have access to QMLEngine in my library